# Failed to Attach to Process ID Xcode in ionic 2 application of ios

Tags: angular, typescript, ios-simulator, xcode7, ionic2

I am new to ionic application.
See my system setup-

```
******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,      
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:     

 Install ios-deploy to deploy iOS applications to devices.  `npm install -g ios-deploy` (may require sudo)

******************************************************

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v6.2.2
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68



******************************************************
```

I have seen many tutorials, did as it was mentioned there but i am still getting error.

Can any one hemp me!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am working on Ionic 2 application, I am new to this and even Xcode and simulator.
Initially my app was working on simulator but after some time it start generating error like-
xcode error: failed to attach to process id

I searched for, tried all above answers but my issue was not resolved.
Then I updated ([Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/installation/), [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), [cordova](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova)) my machine setup-

```
******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,      
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:     

 Install ios-deploy to deploy iOS applications to devices.  `npm install -g ios-deploy` (may require sudo)

******************************************************

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v6.2.2
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68



******************************************************
```

After this I just run a command from my application home directory

1. ionic run -l
2. ionic build ios.
3. imported xcode changes to xcode.
4. Reset content and setting as-
   [image]
5. clear product from xcode,
   [image]
6. Run Xcode and now it is working on simulator.

Happy to see this!!!